# How is `nest build` different from a basic `tsc`?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have faced a problem which might require me to stop using NestJS scripts such as `nest build` and go back to calling `tsc` directly. My question is - what does `nest build` do that makes it different from a simple `tsc` call?

I have noticed that it transforms path-mapped imports (those defined under `tsconfig.json > "compilerOptions" > "paths"`) by default, whereas a plugin and a special compiler were previously required to achieve the same result.

I also took a look at the code, of which there's quite a bit. Among other things, there's a custom compiler, so there must be something that's special about `nest build`, right?

Comment: you can find that out by reading the source: https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/blob/3bfecfa11567a4a6418546ef055a3c1aa15e3a2a/actions/build.action.ts#L69